# Killing background processes started in nix-shell

Tags: background-process, trap, nix

I am developing a simple data science [environment](https://github.com/dmvianna/python-nix) with `Python` tools and a database. When I enter the `nix-shell`, I spin up the database process. I would like to spin it down when exiting the environment.

How could I use `trap` and `nix` to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using something like the following:

./shell.nix:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> { };

in with pkgs; mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ glibcLocales postgresql ];

  shellHook = ''
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
           PGDATABASE=some-dbname \
           PGDATA="$PWD/nix/pgdata" \
           PGHOST="$PWD/nix/sockets" \
           PGPORT="5433" \
           PGUSER="$USER"

    trap "'$PWD/nix/client' remove" EXIT
    nix/client add
  '';
}
```

./nix/client

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

client_pid=$PPID

start_postgres() {
    if postgres_is_stopped
    then
        logfile="$PWD/log/pg.log"
        mkdir -p "$PGHOST" "${logfile%/*}"
        (set -m
        pg_ctl start --silent -w --log "$logfile" -o "-k $PGHOST -h ''")
    fi
}

postgres_is_stopped() {
    pg_ctl status >/dev/null
    (( $? == 3 ))
}

case "$1" in
    add)
        mkdir -p nix/pids touch nix/pids/$client_pid
        if [ -d "$PGDATA" ]
        then
            start_postgres
        else
            pg_ctl initdb --silent -o '--auth=trust' && start_postgres && createdb $PGDATABASE
        fi
        ;;
    remove)
        rm nix/pids/$client_pid
        if [ -n "$(find nix/pids -prune -empty)" ]
        then
            pg_ctl stop --silent -W
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: ${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/} {add | remove}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

The `EXIT` trap will shut down the database server if no other nix-shell sessions are still using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an addendum to @ivan's answer on how to invoke more than one command in one `trap`:

```
shellHook =

  let
    # NOTE These are equivalent.
    #
    #      shellHook =        shellHook =  
    #        ''                 ''         
    #          trap \             trap \   
    #          "                  "        
    #        ''                   echo lofa
    #      + ''                   sleep 2  
    #          echo lofa          echo miez  
    #          sleep 2            " \      
    #          echo miez          EXIT     
    #        ''                 ''         
    #      + ''               ;            
    #          " \
    #          EXIT
    #        ''
    #      ;

    # Helper function to achieve the same
    cleanUp =
      shell_commands:
        ''
          trap \
          "
          ${ builtins.concatStringsSep "" shell_commands }
          " \
          EXIT
        ''
    ;

  in

    cleanUp [
      ''
        echo -n "POSTGRES CLEANUP START..."
      ''
      ( builtins.readFile ./postgres/clean-up.sh )
      ''
        echo "END"
      ''
    ]
  ;
```

See also [this post](https://See%20also%20https://elixirforum.com/t/nix-the-package-manager/23231/3) for a longer example.